# Cosinal signals in Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization?

Tags: signal-processing, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I have the following three signals:

$$s_1(t)=\begin{cases}Acos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)  & 0<t<\frac{T}{2} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$s_2(t)=\begin{cases}Acos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)  & 0<t<T \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$s_3(t)=\begin{cases}Acos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)  & \frac{T}{2}<t<T \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

*"Build an orthonormal basis and plot the corresponding signal constellation."*

-The professor says.

It is apparent that it is the **same signal**, only applied at various subsets of time. I tried using the Gram-Schmidt method to break down the signal as: $s_i(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3a_iφ_i(t)$ so I can also plot the signal constellation.

..only to realize that there is clearly a more suitable method I haven't figured out yet.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthonormal basis $\{\phi_k(t)\}^n$ means 
$$\int\phi_i(t)\phi_j(t)dt=\begin{cases}0,&i\neq j\\ 1, &i=j
\end{cases}$$
It is not difficult to realize that $s_1(t)$ and $s_3(t)$ are orthogonal, and $s_2(t)=s_1(t)+s_3(t)$.
So we build the basis using $s_1(t)$ and $s_3(t)$:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{T}{2}}\left(B\cos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)\right)^2dt=\frac{B^2T}{4}=1\Rightarrow B=\frac{2}{\sqrt{T}}$$
Hence, $$\phi_1(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{\sqrt{T}}\cos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)& 0<t<\frac{T}{2} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and similarly, 
$$\phi_2(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{\sqrt{T}}\cos\left(\frac{2πt}{T}\right)& \frac{T}{2}<t<T \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
So we have $$s_1(t)=\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}\phi_1(t)+0\phi_2(t)\Rightarrow \mathbf{s}_1=[\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2},0]$$
$$s_2(t)=\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}\phi_1(t)+\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}\phi_2(t)\Rightarrow \mathbf{s}_2=[\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2},\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}]$$
$$s_3(t)=0\phi_1(t)+\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}\phi_2(t)\Rightarrow \mathbf{s}_3=[0,\frac{A\sqrt{T}}{2}]$$